# How to trigger a function in ionic 3 and angular 4 when the app is in background mode?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I am developing an app for IOT. in iot device they have a sim card and customers will feed their mobile number. so whenever there is an event it will send a message to the customer.
Now in app i am storing the iot device sim number and whenever there is a message from the device i need to read and show it in the app. 
Everything is working as expected when the app is in foreground. but whenever the app is going to background, i cannot able to read the message.
So please help me to solve this issue. i tried ionic background-mode package but no use.

```
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(()=>{      
  if (SMS) SMS.startWatch(() => {
    console.log('watching started');
  }, Error => {
    console.log('failed to start watching');
  });

  document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e: any) => {
    var sms = e.data;
      if (sms.address == '+91' + this.global.deviceNumber) {
        var messageArray = new Array();
        messageArray=sms.body.split('\n');
        this.messageReceiver(messageArray);
      }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that after android 6 they removed app's working in background mode. so to wake up user we need to use push notifications, or we can run schedulers.